# observable list angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observable

I'm new to Rx and have problems to get what i want. please help:
i want to get a list of User Profiles Ids for a List of UserIds
I have a problem merging all the results to one Observable

```
getListOfUsers(): Observable< Profile[]> {
  let users = this.af.database.list('listOfUsers/');

  let singleuser = users.flatMap(
    (users)=> {
      console.log(users);
      return users.map( singleuser => {
        return singleuser;
      })
    } 
  );


  return singleuser.flatMap(
  (profile) => {
    return this.af.database.object('profiles/' + profile['$key']).map(
      singleprofile => {
        console.log(singleprofile);
        return singleprofile;
      }
    );
  });
}
```

This function gives me back single Profile Objects, how can i merge all of them to one list of Profile Objects? I tryed to wrap the return function with Observable.forkjoin and some other stuff but nothing worked for me.
Is there any option to use the whole list in the second call instead of splitting it to single users first?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
let users = this.af.database.list('listOfUsers/');
var profiles = users.flatMap(t => 
        Observable.forkJoin(
             t.map(x => this.af.database.object('profiles/' + x.uid))
        )
    );
return profiles;
```

Comment: thank you! Still doesnt work. this looks good as far as i can tell, but it does not work.I guess the "inner" observable does never complete so the forkJoin doesnt either.

Comment: made a slight change. the URL is now `profiles/{userId}`

Comment: the data is ok and arriving, so the profile link is also fine. the only thing i cant get to work is the forkjoin. if i add a .do(
            res => {
              console.log(res) to the inner observable i can see all the profiles, but the forkjoin does nothing

Comment: The forkJoin should return an Observable<Profile[]> where its resolved when the underlying array of observables is resolved. Looks suitable here.

Comment: hm, still cant get it to work. in my component i simply subscribe to the service like this:  `this.firebaseService.getListOfUsers().subscribe(
      (userProfiles) => {
        console.log(userProfiles);
      });` This should be fine? What am i missing? Any ideas? Are there any other options to replace forkjoin?

Comment: got it to work with combineLatest instead of forkJoin. i wonder why forkJoin didnt work. my userId is now included in the resultobjects, this could be useful later. thank you @pixelbits

Comment: `forkJoin` doesn't work because AngularFire2 lists and objects don't complete; they re-emit if/when the database changes. To use `forkJoin`, you'd need to use `first` or `take(1)` to complete the object observable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your function to return an `Observable<UserProfile[]>` instead of `Observable<UserProfile>` then you need to add `.toArray()` so all emissions are put into one array emission:

```
return singleuser.flatMap(
  profile => this.af.database.object('profiles/' + profile['$key'])
)
.toArray();
```